# Is there a way to determine by Apex if `Grant Access Using Hierarchies` is turned on or off?

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

We have a requirement to display list of records available at territory selected.

Since `Grant Access Using Hierarchies` can be turned on or off this can affect the records we need to display. We don't find any way in Apex to determine if `Grant Access Using Hierarchies` can be turned on or off to handle this correctly.

The problem is that we need to display this view under administrator and Admin has access to all the territories, so we can't just query records.
Also records can be shared down and up. Down by sharing them with Territory and Subordinates and up by `Grant Access Using Hierarchies`.

So without having this option we are unable to meet our client needs

Comment: Could you explain your issue a bit briefly. Because which you are trying to share with whom

Comment: I am not trying to share anything, I have just requirements to display list of records which are available for each territory. To query those records I need to know if Grant Access Using Hierarchies is turned on to find if sharing to child territories should be included

Comment: Have you looked into UserRecordAccess object?

Comment: @javanoob this won't help, since they may not be a user which has access only to one territory and it doesn't make sense to create a user just to verify which records are available in a territory

Comment: is the generalization of this:  _show all records that can be seen by a user other than the running user_ ?

Comment: @cropredy no, I don't think so, since this is: 'show all records that can be seen in the current territory including shared from territories below or above in the territory hierarchy'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this option is not available neither by Apex, nor by Tooling API, SOAP API or Metadata API. So the only option to achieve this is screenscraping.

```
public static Boolean hasGrantAccessUsingHierarchies(String entityName) {


String entityId = [select DurableId from Entitydefinition where DeveloperName = :entityName].DurableId;

String u = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + 
    '/p/own/OrgSharingDetail?setupid=SecuritySharing&div_filter=&st=' + entityId;
PageReference p = new PageReference(u);
String x = p.getContent().toString();
String y = x.substringBetween(' booleanColumn">', '</td>');
Boolean z = y.contains('/img/checkbox_checked.gif');
 return z;}
String entityName = 'CustomObject';

System.debug(hasGrantAccessUsingHierarchies(entityName));
```

However, this might not pass Security Review, since this is fragile as any screen-scraping methods.

Also I posted idea to get a better option https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015AhkQAE

Comment: If you get the chance I would suggest you raise an idea for adding this access and post the link to it here so folks can upvote it.

Comment: @PhilW definitely. Posted and I am going to update my answer.   https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015AhkQAE